# how to get Patients details using mmjmenu php api?

Tags: php, api

I want to get patients details using MMJMenu api from my php application.

we can easily get MMJMenu items using it's api to our application but how to Patients details using api

Here using this code to get menuitems...

```
<?php
     require 'API/Mmjmenu.php';
     $client = new Mmjmenu('JHDGFDS46JSsdf654FSJHDSH');

     $menuItems      = $client->menuItems();
     $menuItems      = json_decode($menuItems, true);

     foreach($menuItems['menu_items'] as $item)
     {
          echo $item['name'];
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the API documentation for MMJMenu, you will see that you can only get Un-confirmed patients through the API. You cannot currently get a full list of patients through the MMJMenu API. See https://mmjmenu.com/docs/api/patients

Comment: thanks once again...for giving me right answer....give up vote to my question i accept your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Unless $menuItems['menu_items'] also is an array (which I doubt), you should be able to fix the issue by switching it to

```
foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem) {
    echo $menuItem;
 }
```

Comment: i want to list patients from account....above code is working properly but it for menu items..

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you expect someone to magically come up with the solution without seeing any other code. If you could upload your api file somewhere, I could assist you much better.

Comment: if you don't know about mmjmenu api than it out of your knowledge...and all the required code is here i mention...